# _tkinter.TclError: image "..." doesn't exists no matter how I code

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I know that this has question has been asked and solved already, buy I still keep having the same issue.

```
def showpopup(self, event, item):
    global r

    if str(event.type) == "Enter":
        r = tk.Tk()
        r.geometry("400x900+{:}+{:}".format(self.winfo_rootx()+840, self.winfo_rooty()))
        r.wm_title("Pop UP")
        r.overrideredirect(True)
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(images_db_dir, "a.png"))
        imaitem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        r.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        r.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        mf = tk.Frame(r)
        mf.grid(row = 0, column=0, sticky="nsew")    

        mf.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        f1, f2 = tk.Frame(mf, , tk.Frame(mf, background="red")
        f1.place(x=5, y=5, anchor="nw", width=390, height=390)
        f2.place(x=0, y=405, anchor="nw", width=400, height=400)

        l = tk.Label(f1, image = imaitem)
        l.image = imaitem
        l.grid()
        r.mainloop()

    elif str(event.type) == "Leave":
        r.destroy()
```

This program is a part of a big one that shows a "pop up" (made by a tkinter object) when the event.type is "Enter" and destroy it when is "Leave". In any case, eventhough I keep the reference by coding l.image = imaitem the code breaks in the line before this one.
When I running it, it says that the image doesn't exists eventhough the "pop up" appears and works fine when instead of an image a text is coded inside the label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Yes, and I've tried with other images and it happens the same. When I run the main program it gets the images perfectly, but not when running the "pop up".

Comment: If showpopup is getting called from another Tkinter window, you should use Toplevel() instead of Tk(). You shouldn't/can't have two Tk() instances.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now works perfectly by coding tk.Toplevel() , I've been stack here for a while, you made my day!

Comment: Glad it helped. :) Adding an answer just to make sure this doesn't stay as _unanswered_.

Answer (score 0):

If `showpopup` is getting called from another Tkinter window, you should use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`. You can't have two `Tk()` instances.